# ¿Como ver los resultados de cada uno de los clasificadores entrenados usando la clase sklearn.multiclass.OneVsOneClassifier?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, knn

Estoy usando la clase `OneVsOneClassifier` de `sklearn` en un problema de clasificación multiclase. Los resultados generales van bien, pero quisiera saber si existe alguna forma de visualizar los resultados de los clasificadores que utiliza el enfoque *one-vs-one*. El código que tengo hasta ahora es este:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsOneClassifier
import pandas as pd
from scipy.spatial.distance import braycurtis
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

df_X = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df_Y = pd.read_csv('label.csv')

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(df_X, df_Y, random_state=42)

knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = 5, metric = braycurtis, weights = 'distance')

ovo_knn = OneVsOneClassifier(knn)
ovo_knn.fit(X_train, Y_train)
Y_pred = ovo_knn.predict(X_test)

acc_score = accuracy_score(Y_test, Y_pred)
print("Acierto de KNN en la partición de test:", acc_score)
print(metrics.classification_report(Y_test,Y_pred))

m_confusion = confusion_matrix(Y_test, Y_pred)
print(m_confusion)

mean_accuaracy = ovo_knn.score(X_test,Y_test)
print(f'El accuracy medio es de {mean_accuaracy}')

f1 = metrics.f1_score(Y_test,Y_pred, average='weighted')
print("La medida F1 para el clasificador es %.4f"%(f1))
```